# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package

I do not understand the following problem I am facing.

I have 3 projects, A, B and C. All of them have a reference to `Newtonsoft.Json`, version `12.0.1`

Project a has a reference to both projects B and C.  Project B, has a references to `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`

When I run project A, I get the following runtime error when trying to execute the function necessary for creating my token.

**Message:**

> "The type initializer for 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JsonExtensions' threw an exception."

**Inner Exception:**

> "Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

I have verified that all projects reference the same `Newtonsoft.Json` package with version `12.0.1`.
I have also checked my project files, to make sure there is no reference to `Newtonsoft.Json` version `10.0.0.0`

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried consolidating the nuget package for the entire solution?

Comment: What do you mean consolidating?

Comment: Is it a web project or a windows application? Have a look at _web.config_ or _app.config_, if there's any entry with Newtonsoft.Json and the wrong version number

Comment: @schlonzo One project is an Azure function, the other two projects are class libraries

Comment: You probably need to add an [assembly redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions)

Comment: @Liam Will Check this out

Comment: If you're using packages.config for NuGet references, migrating to PackageReference might solve the problems, as PackageReference supports transitive dependencies (packages.config does not) and generally can automatically generate binding redirects as necessary.

Comment: Do you by any chance have a project within other project folder? Project A has a project A Folder and Project B is inside Project A folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newtonsoft Json while useful is the source of many issues.

You will need to check all the NuGet packages referenced by every project in your solution to see what version of Newtonsoft Json they require. Some specify a minimal version, in which case you don't have an issue (  like > 10, anything higher than 10 will work ), others require a certain, fixed version ( = 10, must be 10, not less, not higher). This is up to the author of that particular NuGet package.

When you hit build, the dlls required by the referenced packages will be copied over, then the dlls required by any referenced projects will copied over and it is possible a certain version will be copied over and when you run your application, you get the error you have seen.

You can check this by looking in the bin folder of your build profile, right click the dll file and inspect its version to see what you have. Assembly redirection should help, when done in the right place, but there is an alternative solution, although it's not always possible.

If you can drop the Newtonsoft Json to the minimum version which satisfies all requirements then that is a good way to solve the problem. Chances are you don't need version 12, depending on what you are using from it and depending on what other packages require. You might be able to change all projects to reference the lower version without any side effects. If you can, you're golden, just make sure you don't upgrade by mistake. If not, you'll have to do the version redirecting like indicated in other answers.

The basic idea is to make sure, that in your solution, you only use one version of Newtonsoft. you can check this package at solution level, there is a consolidate option as well.

So, check all projects in the solution, make sure they all use one version of Newtonsoft and that version is the same across all of them.

Once you manage to get everything on one level make sure that:

1. you delete the Temporary ASp.Net folder contents, in Windows / Microsoft.Net, Framework23 or 64 depends which one you're using.
2. remove all dlls from all bin folders, a simple Cleanup may not be sufficient.

With all this done, providing you have one version everywhere, you should be able to run you project without issues

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have downgraded all Newtonsoft.Json packages in all projects, and still seemed to get the same issue, I am unsure why though, as I made sure.

Comment: I added a few more things to my answer, should help you get everything working

Answer (score 1):

I think some of your project is referring version 10, while other is referring version 12 of newtonsoft.json.dll.

It seems the v12 DLL is getting copied to output directory.  The project which refers v10 is throwing this error.

For all the strong named assemblies, the specific version of DLL is searched in the application directory or GAC.  You can overwrite this default behavior by using below configuration file entry - which instructs .net framework to always look for v12 whenever any version from 0 to 12 is called.

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.1.0" newVersion="12.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Hope this helps to resolve your issue.

Comment: Do I modify this assembly binding in the project that is throwing the error?

Comment: The project that throws the error, has the following bindingRedirect:
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />

Comment: Is it an application (i.e. .EXE) or it is a DLL ?  Please add this binding redirect to the application (exe's ) config file.

Comment: The prject the error is thrown in is a nuget package (DLL)

Comment: As per your question, You are running project "A".  That means you will have to put this binding redirection project A's config file.

Comment: I upvoted. Your answer would have worked if I was not making an Azure Function App.  I had to do a little bit of extra work, as you will see in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this working.  In order to do Assembly Redirect Binding in Azure Functions, it takes a little more effort than a normal `.Net` application.

I followed the following post:
https://codopia.wordpress.com/2017/07/21/how-to-fix-the-assembly-binding-redirect-problem-in-azure-functions/

Answer (score 0):

Find out what project trying to load this library. Right click on project->Manage Nuget Packages->Find NewtonJson library in installed libs and click Uninstall, maybe this will help. Also like people provided before use could you assembly redirect.

Answer (score -1):

Where you are using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt don't add it as a using to the page instead make a direct reference to it.

Comment: I will give this a try.  Mind explaining why you think this should solve it?

Comment: It sounds like whatever is using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt in Class B is trying to use Newtonsoft.Json Version 10.0.0.0 but is getting confused by the Newtonsoft.Json Version 12.0.0.0 which is referenced in class A and C. I may have misunderstood but I have had similar situations to this before. I have also fix this by uninstalling and reinstalling packages